# How to delete a key from a referenced hash?

Tags: perl, hash

I would like to know how can I delete a key from a referenced hash ?
I tried some example which I see on internet but none is working...

```
$dicA->{$keysA} = "\$";
delete($dicA{$keysA});
```

That method isn't working and it's giving me that error (which I don't know)

> Error:  Global symbol "%dic" requires explicit package name at /Users/.../PrefixTree.pm line 217.
>        (line 217 -> delete line)

I would like to have some advice please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some problems.

First, use the `strict` and `warnings` pragmas.

Second, declare variables before using them:

```
my ($dicA, $keysA);
```

Third, `$dicA->{}` and `$dicA{}` are different variables. The first one is a scalar reference, and the second one is a hash. Use the same one:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my $dicA;
my $keysA = 'key';

$dicA->{$keysA} = "\$";
delete($dicA->{$keysA});
```

Answer (score 2):

Like so `delete $dicA->{$keysA};` or in a more complete example

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

$keysA='Hello';
$dicA = {};
$dicA->{$keysA} = "\$";

print "$dicA\n";
print "key \"$dicA->{$keysA}\"\n";
delete $dicA->{$keysA};
print "$dicA\n";
print "key \"$dicA->{$keysA}\"\n";
```